# Java Object extending a list to Json with Jackson

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jackson, marshalling

I want to convert a object that is extending a list to Json using Jackson. 
Example:

```
public class TryToSerialize extends ArrayList<String>
{
    private int number;
    private String word;

    public TryToSerialize(){
        number = 0;
        word = "";
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getAsJSON() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\tts.json"), this);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this) ; 
    }
}
```

When I do serialize this I will only get the Array portion.

```
    TryToSerialize tts = new TryToSerialize();
    tts.setNumber(10);
    tts.setWord("Working");
    tts.add("first");
    tts.add("second");
    tts.add("third");
    String json = tts.getAsJSON();
```

Json:

```
["first","second","third"]
```

I am looking for a way to include the other variables of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your object extends one of the classes for which a default serialization behavior exists, your extra fields are just ignored.

Now, one thing which is unclear to me is what should be the expected result.

If you are expecting a result such as:

```
{"number":10,"word":"Working","values":["first","second","third"]}
```

Then you should be able to do it thanks to a custom serializer such as the following:

```
public class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<TryToSerialize> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(TryToSerialize toSerialize, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("number", toSerialize.getNumber());
        jgen.writeStringField("word", toSerialize.getWord());
        provider.defaultSerializeField("values", toSerialize.iterator(), jgen);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

If you are expecting a result such as:

```
[10,"Working","first","second","third"]
```

Then, serializer will look like the following:

```
public class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<TryToSerialize> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(TryToSerialize toSerialize, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        jgen.writeNumber(toSerialize.getNumber());
        jgen.writeString(toSerialize.getWord());
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = toSerialize.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            jgen.writeString((String) iterator.next());         
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Then, in both cases annotate your class with:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MySerializer.class)
```

There may be a smarter ways but this should work...

Comment: Awesome that works. Would you happen to know how to deserialize it?

Comment: You will need a custom deserializer ;)

Comment: However, wouldn't it be a better design if you modified your TryToSerialize class so that it delegates to ArrayList rather than inherits from it? (if the first of the two output quoted above is acceptable). This would (de)serialize with the default (de)serializers.